# Angular - Two way binding input property to component with getters / setters

Tags: angular, getter-setter, property-binding

I have the following angular components:

`ComponentB` which has an input property, and `componentA` which insert `componentB` in the template file.
The code looks as the following:

componentA.ts:

```
export class ComponentA{
    isOpen: boolean;

    methodA() {
        this.isOpen = false;
        // do some work
    }
}
```

componentA.html:

```
<componentB [(open)]="isOpen"></componentB >
```

ComponentB.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'componentB',
    templateUrl: 'ComponentB .html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class ComponentB {

    private _open: boolean = false;

    @Input('open') set open(value: boolean) {
        if (open === this._open) {
            return;
        }
        if (open) {
            // doSomething()
        } else {
            // doSomethingElse()
        }
        this._open = open;
    }

    get open() {
        return this._open;
    }
}
```

The issue is that `isOpen` property doesn't seems to reflect the current value of `open` property, although two way binding was specified.

Why does it happens?
How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two way binding is a special syntax that angular provides to set **the value of a component** and **listen to value changes** at the same time.

> For this purpose special syntax (Banana in a box) "**[()]**" is used. Please find the official angular documentation about this [here](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding).

In a nutshell, you'll have to provide one property with **@Input()** decorator, and one property with **@Output()** decorator. The @Output() property will have the word **Change** appended to it. So if the @Input property name was **x** then the output property name shall be **xChange**. And whenever the underlying bound property is changed, using the **EventEmitter** of the output property, let the parent component listen to the change (hence two way binding implemented).

In your case your code would update like this

```js
  @Input('open') set open(value: boolean) {
        if (value === this._open) {
            return;
        }
        if (open) {
            // doSomething()
        } else {
            // doSomethingElse()
        }
        this._open = value;
        this.openChange.emit(this._open); //open value set, the updated value is emitted using the output property.
    }
    get open() {
        return this._open;
    }
      @Output('openChange')  //the output property added
      openChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

Please find the [Stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4rylqu?file=src/app/component-a/component-a.component.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

```
private _open= false;

@Input('open') set open(value: boolean) {
    if (value=== this._open) {
        return;
    }
    if (value) {
        // doSomething()
    } else {
        // doSomethingElse()
    }
    this._open = value;
}

get open() {
    return this._open;
}
```

can you try this ?

btw @Input() open : boolean = false; is a lint mistake. when you assign = false to value it's type will automatically assign as boolean you don't have to specify it

Comment: Tnx! but wWhen I access the value of `isOpen` from `componentA` (after view init)  it's value is still undefined

Comment: Why don't you use output?


`@Output() onValueChange : EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
private _open= false;

@Input('open') set open(value: boolean) {
    if (value=== this._open) {
        return;
    }
    if (value) {
        // doSomething()
    } else {
        // doSomethingElse()
    }
    this._open = value;
    this.onValueChange.emit(value);
}

get open() {
    return this._open;
}`

in ComponentA html

`<componentB [(open)]="isOpen" (onValueChange)="methodHere($event)"></componentB >`

in ComponentA .ts

`onValueChange(open: boolean){

}`

Comment: and also if you want to avoid undefined in child component you should check if input equal undefined in setter. Maybe you're sending undefined as a variable to child component hence it couldn't take it's default variable but takes undefined as variable. 

`@Input('open') set open(value: boolean) {
if(value !== undefined){
    if (value=== this._open) {
        return;
    }
    if (value) {
        // doSomething()
    } else {
        // doSomethingElse()
    }
    this._open = value;
}
}`

Comment: for else block  you should equal _open to false